# Get the value text of a link starting from div

Tags: jquery

How do I get the text value of cp5 hello world by starting with the div MrJ.

```
<div id="MrJ">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="http://www.test.com/">h</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.test.com/cp5/">cp5 hello world</a>
</li>
<li>subcat</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is where I'm at:

```
alert($('#MrJ').find('ul li').find('a:gt(1)');
```

Comment: Is the `text()` method what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert($('#MrJ ul li a:eq(1)').text());
```

First, you want `:eq(1)`, not `:gt(1)`, since the one you want is number 1.

Second, use the `.text()` method to get the text content of an element.

And you don't need to call `find()` repeatedly, just put all the selectors together.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/K8Ram/)

Comment: man why isn't this working, i can never get the syntax of jquery right /facepalm.